# Interpret learning curves: Training error and validation error are low

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I am confused about how to evaluate this result. From this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187404/157549), it seems like my model is just right, I just want to make sure that my result is a good fit. Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

zoom:
[image]

Comment: What are the units for error?

Comment: The unit for error is the amount of the links utilization. Please correct me if something's wrong here. Thanks, Mike!

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer on how to read learning curve here. I think it may be helpful.

[How to know if a learning curve from SVM model suffers from bias or variance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220827/how-to-know-if-a-learning-curve-from-svm-model-suffers-from-bias-or-variance/220852#220852)

I would suggest you to use more data, instead of 1 to 27 data points. The reason is in your plot, the numbers are easily get very small after passing $n=3$ and the $y$ axis is in a larger scale.

In sum,

- Try to use more data
- Try to make y axis scale smaller to clearly see two lines.

Comment: Thanks, hxd1011. From what I've learned from ML, there is a high bias (underfit) when J_{train}{\theta} is high and J_{cross-validate}(\theta) ~  J_{train}{\theta}, so getting more data will not help much. There is a high variance (overfit) when J_{train}(\theta) is low and J_{cross-validate}(\theta) >> J_{train}{\theta}, so getting more data is likely to help. But in my case, J_{train}(\theta) is low, J_{cross-validate}(\theta)~J_{train}(\theta). That's why I am confused about this situation. As the data are pretty scarce in my case, are there alternatives to solve it without using more data?